# warning CS8012: Referenced assembly targets a different processor. What are the consequences?

Tags: c#, cpu-architecture, .net-assembly

warning CS8012: Referenced assembly 'NationalInstruments.DAQmx, Version=19.1.45.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4febd62461bf11a4' targets a different processor.

I know what this message is telling me and how to fix it, but I wonder why it is only a warning and what the runtime consequences are.

Comment: I reckon that assembly of yours targets Any CPU, and referenced one is x86 or x64? There is no way to predict where the assembly is going to be executed, so the resposibility is shifted to the developer. It is perfectly valid to have some Any CPU and some x86 running in x86-compatible environment. Or Any CPU/x64 in x64 env. However, mixing x64 and x86 in one process is pretty much impossible so you're guaranteed to have the process crash if it is Any CPU/x64 started in x86 environment.
There is a technique to use x86/x64 assemblies, depending on current env's bitness, you may want to check it